# Facebook fan gating / reveal tab using only Javascript OR .net?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I started developing on Facebook just before the recent/ongoing changes and now when I try to build an app I'm just completely lost. There's quite a few similar questions related to my query (it's obviously a very popular feature) but I'm wondering whether there is a relatively up-to-date method of creating a fan-gating feature only using Javascript? Some people are convinced you can create a fully functioning (as in the 'usual' php way) fan gate with just JS but I'm a bit skeptical how this could be possible. Where should I start?

Also, while I'm at it, I still haven't discovered a working .net method of this feature either . Again, I've read many people say this isn't possible, and many saying it is. Anyone have any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

I've put into effect a fan-gate using both the C# API as well as the Javascript API.  What have you tried?